# Microsoft Azure - How to disable auto log about network?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm new in Azure. I'm using Serial console in Azure. But when I do some command line, it's usually auto display log about Network config:

> 2018/10/17 14:39:47.352448 INFO ExtHandler Updated NIC state: [{ "name": "brovc", "link": " mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/ether 52:54:00:ed:b2:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 \    bridge forward_delay 200 hello_time200 max_age 2000 ageing_time 30000 stp_state 1 priority 32768 vlan_filtering 0 vlan_protocol 802.1Q bridge_id 8000.52:54:0:ed:b2:e5 designated_root 8000.52:54:0:ed:b2:e5 root_port 0 root_path_cost 0 topology_change 0 topology_change_detected 0 hello_timer    0.65 tcn_timer    0.00 topology_change_timer    0.00 gc_timer   55.41 vlan_default_pvid 1 vlan_stats_enabled 0 group_fwd_mask 0 group_address 01:80:c2:00:00:00 mcast_snooping 1 mcast_router 1 mcast_query_use_ifaddr 0 mcast_querier 0 mcast_hash_elasticity 4 mcast_hash_max 512 mcast_last_member_count 2 mcast_startup_query_count 2 mcast_last_member_interval100 mcast_membership_interval 26000 mcast_querier_interval 25500 mcast_query_interval 12500 mcast_query_response_interval 1000 mcast_startup_query_interval 3125 mcast_stats_enabled 0 mcast_igmp_version 2 mcast_mld_version 1 nf_call_iptables 0 nf_call_ip6tables 0 nf_call_arptables 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 " }, { "name": "lo", "link": " mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000\    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 " }, 
>   ...

How to disable this log?